# Are scheduled Part 135 flights allowed at Teterboro (KTEB)?

Tags: faa-regulations, airport-operations, far-135

The Port Authority states that “[A]s a reliever airport, it does not offer scheduled airline service,” however, it seems like a few companies offer scheduled flights (or so they advertise), albeit with private jets. Are scheduled Part 135 flights allowed at KTEB, or is this operation prohibited by some rule?

Comment: "It **does** not" and "it **may** not" do not mean the same thing...

Answer (score 2):

Scheduled airline service would be part 121 operations. Part 135 is for charter services, and limited scheduled service with strict limits on number of passengers and cargo weight. Teterboro does allow unscheduled part 135 charter flights.

Comment: What about scheduled 135 flights (with the restrictions you mentioned)?

Comment: @CharlesNicholson For a definitive answer you would need to call them.